# Как поменять кодировку metadata данных, направляемых в String?

Tags: android, utf-8, textview, charset, metadata

Здравствуйте, получаю названия песен через **metadata**. Некоторые названия песен приходят в неправильной кодировке с серверов., как можно сделать так, чтобы результат `String s` был в нужной мне кодировке? (UTF-8 получается нужно).

```
private StreamMetaData parseMetadata(final String s) {
        Log.d(TAG, "metadata=%s", s);

        final String[] parts = s.split(";");
        final StreamMetaData metadata = new StreamMetaData();

        for (String part : parts) {
            final int index = part.indexOf('=');
            if (index < 0)
                continue;
            final String key = part.substring(0, index);
            final String value = part.substring(index + 2, part.length() - 1);
            Log.d(TAG, "key=%s / value=%s", key, value);
            metadata.put(key, value);
        }
        return metadata;
    }
```

P.S: вызываю показ названия песни в своей активити с помощью данной строчки:

```
nowPlayingView.setText(Streamer.getInstance().getLastMetaData().getTitle());
```

Может тут намного всё проще, и нужно дописать что-то к этой строчке сверху, но я не знаю. Заранее спасибо за все советы и всю помощь!